# C# LINQ ADO Entity

Tags: c#, ado, entity-framework, linq

Я хочу получить лучшие пять ресторанов из моей базы данных . Структура базы данных усложняет мой LINQ запрос.

Вот как я работаю, у меня есть таблица `Комментарии` , которая содержит внешний ключ в таблицу `Ресторан` и у меня есть три варианта для голосования от 1 до 5 .

Пример таблицы :

- IdRestaurant
- RatingOne
- RatingTwo
- RatingThree

Поэтому я хотел бы отсортировать ресторан по среднему рейтингу (считается на основе трех показателей рейтинга в БД)

Если, например, у меня есть несколько записей в таблице

idRestaurant 1 - RatingOne 2 - RatingTwo 2 - RatingThree - 2

idRestaurant 1 - RatingOne : 4 - RatingTwo : 4 - RatingThree - 4

idRestaurant 2 - RatingOne : 3 - RatingTwo : 3 - RatingThree - 3

idRestaurant 2 - RatingOne : 4 - RatingTwo : 4 - RatingThree - 4

idRestaurant : 3 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 3 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 1 - RatingTwo 1 - RatingThree - 1

idRestaurant : 4 - RatingOne 5 - RatingTwo 5 - RatingThree - 5

Я хотел бы, чтобы результат моей LINQ вывел мне список idRestaurants в порядке общей оценки без дублирования сущности ресторан
Например:
{ 2,1,4,3 }

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var ent = new[]
        {
           new {  idRestaurant =  1, RatingOne = 2, RatingTwo = 2, RatingThree = 2 }, 
           new {  idRestaurant =  1, RatingOne = 4, RatingTwo = 4, RatingThree = 4 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  2, RatingOne = 3, RatingTwo = 3, RatingThree = 3 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  2, RatingOne = 4, RatingTwo = 4, RatingThree = 4 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  3, RatingOne = 1, RatingTwo = 1, RatingThree = 1 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  3, RatingOne = 1, RatingTwo = 1, RatingThree = 1 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  4, RatingOne = 1, RatingTwo = 1, RatingThree = 1 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  4, RatingOne = 1, RatingTwo = 1, RatingThree = 1 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  4, RatingOne = 1, RatingTwo = 1, RatingThree = 1 },
           new {  idRestaurant =  4, RatingOne = 5, RatingTwo = 5, RatingThree = 5 }
        };

        var av = ent.Select(e => new { Id = e.idRestaurant, avg = e.RatingOne + e.RatingTwo + e.RatingThree })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                        .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Avg = x.Average(y => y.avg) })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Avg);;

            foreach (var a in av)
                Console.WriteLine("Id = {0}, Avg = {1:F}", a.Id, a.Avg);
```

Впрочем, есть ощущение, что можно сделать несколько проще, но результат тот, что вы ожидаете:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "Впрочем, есть ощущение, что можно сделать несколько проще" *DreamChild*

Оптимизировал, `Select()` лишний.

```
int bestRestaurantCount = 5;
var av = ent
    .GroupBy(x => x.idRestaurant, y => y.RatingOne + y.RatingTwo + y.RatingThree,
        (x, y) => new { Id = x, Rating = y.Average() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating)
    .Take(bestRestaurantCount);
```